# why Moto x play does not have contacts feature like samsung? why it does not have an option to save contacts to phone memory?

Tags: contacts, moto-x-play

I am little bit disappointed after buying Motorola phone. I was aware that it removes bloatware app but on the other hand, it has very poor contacts app/feature. I had earlier used Samsung phones and the contact feature is remarkable,quite user friendly. Here, in Moto X Play, I do not find any option to save contacts on my phone memory. All it has, is the email account. I had recommended this phone to others and I regret my decision.

Anyways, please help me out if there is any option/tweak to make the contacts features better.

Comment: There's a place called "Google Play Store", where you can find alternative contact apps. You can also take a look at my list for [Contact Managers and Dialers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_dialer).

Comment: 1) We can't know why Moto X doesn't have similar features unless there's Motorola representative here (perhaps since there's no SD card? But still, opinion based). 2) the rest of the post reads like a rant, which doesn't help solving the issue. 3) it's unclear what do you mean by option/tweak, making it too broad... and the best suggestion is... try another contact manager app?

Comment: Regretting buying an X Play over a Samsung just because it doesn't have an option to save contacts to phone memory seems strange. Also, try the Export Contacts to Internal Storage option if available.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **Export contacts** to **Storage** in the Phone app after clicking on the 3 dots in the top right corner. That will create a file with all contacts in phone memory.

If that's not what you want you can always download an application of your choice from the Play Store as others have said earlier.